# (vb.net) send a SOAP envelope

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

I consume a web service ([available there](https://www.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpgem-sqa/billService)) and I need to generate and to send a SOAP envelope, but it's not something i do understand.
I've found this example: http://macunsw.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/vb-net-example-for-calling-web-service-by-posting-soap-xml/
but still, i do not get it, the envelope i need to send is like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.sunat.gob.pe" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"> 
<soapenv:Header> 
<wsse:Security> 
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>20100066603MODDATOS</wsse:Username> 
<wsse:Password>moddatos</wsse:Password> 
</wsse:UsernameToken> 
</wsse:Security> 
</soapenv:Header> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<ser:sendBill> 
<fileName>20100066603-01-F001-1.zip</fileName> 
<contentFile>cid:20100066603-01-F001-1.zip</contentFile> 
</ser:sendBill> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone help? thx

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using VB.Net you're not required to handle the SOAP services on your own.

Add the WSDL path `http://...?wsdl` as a remote Service:

- in the Solution Explorer rightclick your project
- Choose `Add Service Reference` from the context menu
- enter the path to WSDL in the Address field & Click Go
- the billService should be found
- choose a namespace, i.e. Sunat

From now on you can access the service as a simple object:

```
Dim billService As New Sunat.billServiceClient
billService.sendBill(fileName, contentFile)
billService.sendSummary(fileName, contentFile)
billService.getStatus(ticket)
```

Comment: `billService.sendBill('20100066603-01-F001-1.zip', File.ReadAllBytes('/path/to/file/20100066603-01-F001-1.zip'))` should do the trick

Comment: the web service is already present in my project, I simply use the sendBill method (as sendSummary and getStatus are particular functions).
My code is :

`Dim ws as Homologacion.billServiceClient
Dim l_return as byte()
Dim data as Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(zipfilename)
ws.ClientCredentials.CreateSecurityTokenManager()
ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username"
ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd"

ws.open()
l_return = ws.sendBill(zipfilename, data)
ws.close()`


But I obtain the error the zip file name isn't correct, i'm pretty sure i didn't misspell it.

Comment: I would have heaps of things to explain on how this web service works, in a guide, it explains a SOAP envelope has to be sent. I can link it to you but it's in spanish
ps: Homologacion is how i named my web service

Comment: The proxy class added to your project handles all the SOAP envelope creation and sending. You could actually check with a traffic capturing software, i.e. Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Concerning the error message, is zipFilename an relative or absolute path? I would assume, that this might be an issue, since the service call will only accept a filename, but not a filepath.

Comment: it seems you resolved this prob i have, now, i've a new one and i've absolutely no clue of how to solve it as it's not related to programming language, the new prob i've is related to authorizations ... thx anyway